# How to show a loading screen when fetching data from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Here is my code section in which i am signing in user using firebase, now i wanted to show a loadihng screen while we are fetching data from firebase.

```
Container(
                  width: 376,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: <Color>[
                        Colors.black12,
                        Colors.blue,
                        Colors.black12,
                      ]
                    )
                  ),
                  child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () async{
                   if(key.currentState!.validate()){
                    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: User_email_id.text, password: user_Passowrd.text)
                        .then((value) => {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Page_First())
                          )
                    }).catchError((e){
                      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e!.message);
                    });
                   }
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Sign-in',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 17,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: I'd look into FutureBuilder: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add boolean isLoading = false to the top of you class. Then move firebase loading code to a separate Future like this:

```
Future<void> loadFirebase(BuildContext context) async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: User_email_id.text, password: user_Passowrd.text)
        .then((value) => {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Page_First())
      )
    }).catchError((e){
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e!.message);
    });
  }
```

This function shall be called when the button is pressed. At the same time, isLoading shall be set to true. Finally, when building your widget, add a condition to show loading screen if isLoading is true.

```
isLoading == true ? LoadingContainer() : Container(content with button);
```